# Bounds for constructing $n!$ with additions, subtractions, and multiplications starting from $1$

Tags: nt.number-theory, computational-complexity

Found this on [Complexity Zoo warning expired certificate](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:N)
check NP Over The Complex Numbers.

> [BCS+97] show the following striking result. For a positive integer $n$, let $t(n)$ denote the minimum number of additions, subtractions, and multiplications needed to construct $n$, starting from 1. If for every sequence ${n_k}$ of positive integers, $t(n_k k!)$ grows faster than polylogarithmically in $k$, then $P_C$ does not equal $NP_C$.

[BCS+97] L. Blum, F. Cucker, M. Shub, and S. Smale. Complexity and Real Computation, Springer-Verlag, 1997.

Couldn't find the paper online, so the exact definition would be helpful.

> What are bounds for $t(n!)$?

---

> **Added later** What are bounds for $t(a n!)$ where $a$ is nonzero and no other properties of $a$ are required?

---

Didn't spend much time, but couldn't solve this:

> Find $a>1,k>1$ and $t(a k!) < t(k!)$.

---

**Added** I doubt this is of any practical interest because
of the space complexity of factorial.

$$    n\log\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)+1 \leq \log n! $$

In OEIS [A025201    a(n) = floor(log(n!)).](https://oeis.org/A025201).

We have $n!=\Gamma(n+1)$ and $\log \log \Gamma(2^{1000})=699.6\ldots$
and $\log \log 2^{2^{1000}}=692.7\ldots$.

Even if an oracle computes the factorial, it is impossible to
store in the computer space of all computers on earth.

---

**Added later** Comment from *Gerhard "Wants To See Better Bounds" Paseman*

> I'd like to add that a similar sounding problem https://mathoverflow.net/a/75792/3206 using additions and multiplications has easy lower and upper bounds of O(log n). The computation model for this problem is different from the above problem, as "repeated subterms" do not add to the complexity of the computation, to state the matter (from memory) roughly. Gerhard "Wants To See Better Bounds" Paseman, 2015.01.26

References for the above answer in OEIS: http://oeis.org/A005245

Comment: This question would be much more likely to receive an expert answer at cstheory. However, unless something changed recently (unlikely), no nontrivial unconditional lower bounds on the arithmetic circuit complexity of $n!$ are known.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Thanks, but I am interested from number theory point of view, not from complexity point of view. Don't like starting a "tag war" and would appreciate the numbertheory tag.

Comment: Your question is what is the arithmetic circuit complexity of factorial, which is a complexity problem, no matter what point of view you take to approach the problem. Put the nt tag back if you think the problem has anything to do with number theory apart from the fact that it involves numbers, but don't remove the complexity tag.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek OK, kept your tag :-) Similar sequences are on OEIS.

Comment: But back to complexity: see https://rjlipton.wordpress.com/2009/02/23/factoring-and-factorials/ for a well-known connection of the problem to the complexity of factoring.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek OK, I am interested what number theorists say about this open problem.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek I edited addressing space complexity of factorial. I doubt Lipton's factoring is of any practical importance even if an oracle computes the factorial, since it is impossible to store $2^{1000}!$ on all computers on earth.

Comment: I think you missed the point of the reduction. You evaluate the circuit modulo something of polynomial length, so all intermediate results are small.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Factorial modulo n is completely different problem for me and possibly might be speeded by factoring not sure. In Lipton's blog I don't see modulo n, in which formula it is?

Comment: Search for "There is one missing, but critical point."

Comment: @EmilJeřábek I see, missed that, the algorithm is practical. Is it within reach to show that implementation on current hardware can't efficiently compute factorial? From experience basic operations on numbers taking tens of gigabytes of RAM are not fast and probably close to the bound for factorial?

Comment: I'd like to add that a similar sounding problem http://mathoverflow.net/a/75792/3206 using additions and multiplications has easy lower and upper bounds of O(log n).  The computation model for this problem is different from the above problem, as "repeated subterms" do not add to the complexity of the computation, to state the matter (from memory) roughly.  Gerhard "Wants To See Better Bounds" Paseman, 2015.01.26

Comment: @joro In *Gnang, Radziwill, Sanna - Counting arithmetic formulas* (http://arxiv.org/abs/1406.1704) the authors proved (Theorem 1.4) that for _almost all_ positive integers $n$ the number of 1's, additions and multiplications (no subtractions) needed to write an arithmetic formula evaluating to $n$ is greater than $C \log n$, for some constant $C > 0$. Therefore, if the factorial $n!$ has *nothing special* (which I doubt is the case) it requires at least $C n \log n$ arithmetic operations to be computed.

Comment: @Fry The problem with only 1 is different from the question. It allows arbitrary numbers not only 1.

Comment: @joro Please, explain. In your question I read "the minimum number of additions, subtractions, and multiplications needed to construct n, *starting from 1*". On the other hand, if one can start from arbitrary numbers, then just start from $n!$ and the problem is trivial: $0$ operations are required. Clearly you means something else but I do not understand.

Comment: @Fry I haven't seen the original paper, but my interpretation based on Lipton's blog (check Emil's link): Start from 1 and construct a set of number S. You can use any number from S, e.g: (1+1)*2. Your link doesn't allow 2 in this example.

Comment: In the Gnang et. al. paper cited by Fry, the complexity used there is similar to the term complexity using a certain algebraic method of computation.  The BCSS model (if I recall correctly) does not use term-complexity, but instead allows subterms to be reused without cost, offering a measure which in general is much smaller than that in the Gnang paper.  Thus Gnang's lower bounds do not apply.  As an example, $t(2^{2^n})$ is close to $n$ (using one plus and no minus), which is smaller than Gnang's measure of order $O(2^n)$. Gerhard "Ask Me About Small Computing" Paseman, 2015.01.28

Comment: @GerhardPaseman OK, now I see that arithmetic formulas measure a different type of complexity respect to that in the question.

Comment: Bürgisser http://math-www.uni-paderborn.de/agpb/work/6dich.pdf gives a refinement of the cited result of [BCSS97]: $\mathrm P_{\mathbb C}\ne\mathrm{NP}_{\mathbb C}$ already follows if $t(n!)$ is not polylogarithmically bounded, multiples of $n!$ are not needed here.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek OK, thanks. Experimentally multiples appear better for me.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek From complexity point of view, is computing _multiple_ of factorial as powerful as computing factorial? IIRC sub-exponential SAT solver might cause troubles.

Answer (score 12):

If **Gerhard Paseman** is right that $t(7!)=8$ then
$(k,a)=(7,13)$ is already an example of $t(ak!)<t(k!)$, because
$$
13 \cdot 7! = 65520 = 2^{16} - 2^4
$$
can be reached in six steps from $1$:
$$
1 + 1 = 2, \quad
2 \cdot 2 = 4, \quad
4 \cdot 4 = 16, \quad
16 \cdot 16 = 256, \quad
256 \cdot 256 = 65536,
$$
and finally $65536 - 16 = 65520$.
This also makes $(10,1183)$ a candidate if $10!$ can't be reached
as quickly as the seven steps to $65520^2$.  [Added later:
**Michael Stoll** now confirms that $t(7!)=8$ $-$ and also reports that
it takes nine steps to reach $10!$, and eight for $8!$ and $9!$, so
this seven-step route to $65520^2$ gives $t(ak!)<t(k!)$ also for $k=8,9,10$.
Later yet, Stoll links to [OEIS A217032](http://oeis.org/A217032)
which gives the values of $t(k!)-1$ for all $k \leq 19$; this lets us
give some more examples, such as $16! \, | \, (2^{64}-2^4)^4$ with
$t(16!) = 13$ and $t((2^{64}-2^4)^4) \leq 11$.]

But the asymptotic question is much harder because we don't have
good *lower* bounds on $t(k!)$.  **Gerhard Paseman** gives
an upper bound of $2k$ or maybe $(1+o(1))k$, which is within
a constant factor of what can be done for any number of this size:
if $N < k^k$ we can use $k$ additions to get $1,2,3,\ldots,k$,
then $k-1$ multiplications to reach $k^2, k^3, \ldots, k^k$,
and then $k+k$ more multiplications and additions to reach $N$
via its base-$k$ expansion.  For $t(k!)$ we can reduce this
by a factor $\gg \log k$ for large $k$, because $k!$ is a product of
powers of the $\pi(k)$ primes $p\leq k$.  We can reach all those primes
in $\pi(k) + O(k^{1/2})$ additions: let $r = \lfloor \sqrt{k} \rfloor$,
then add to get $1,2,3,\ldots,r,2r,3r,\ldots, r^2$, and each prime is a sum of
one or two of these.  [**The Masked Avenger** notes that it's a bit faster
to first get all the numbers that occur as gaps $p_n - p_{n-1}$,
and then get from each prime to the next.]
Now use fewer than $\pi(k)$ multiplications to make the products
$$
P_i := \prod_{ip \leq k < (i+1) p} p
$$
for $i=1,2,3,\ldots,r$, and then
$k! = P_1^{\phantom 1} P_2^2 P_3^3 \cdots P_r^r$ times $\pi(r)$ prime powers.

If *that* approach were optimal then we could get $t(ak!) < t(k!)$ by
replacing $\prod_{i=1}^r P_i^i$ by $\left(\prod_{i=1}^r P_i\right)^{2^\rho}$
once $2^\rho \geq r$.  But it seems that in fact $t(k) \ll k^{1/2 + o(1)}$
because one can write $m^2! = \prod_{j=0}^{m-1} Q(jm)$ where
$Q(X) = (X+1) (X+2) (X+3) \cdots (X+m)$ and use FFT-like tricks
to evaluate a degree-$m$ polynomial at $m$ points in only $m \log^A m$
operations.  (See for instance
[this page](http://fredrikj.net/blog/2012/03/factorials-mod-n-and-wilsons-theorem).
I learned of this surprising fact some year back from **Henry Cohn**.
Caveat: some more work might be needed to fit this method into the
$\{+,-,\times\}$ model without losing a factor worse than $k^\epsilon$.
Added later: **Turbo** notes that
[this paper
by Q.Cheng](http://www.cs.ou.edu/~qcheng/paper/factorial.pdf) (of which more in the next paragraph) cites a paper by
Strassen from the 1970's that gives a route to $k!$ in $O(k^{1/2} \log^2 k)$
$\{+,-,\times\}$ steps.)

This might be asymptotically optimal, but proving $t(k!) \gg k^{1/2}$
(or even $t(k) \gg k^\theta$ for some $\theta>0$) seems to be beyond reach.
Meanwhile, Lenstra's ECM (elliptic curve method) for factoring
suggests that $t(ak!)$ can be as small as $\exp O(\sqrt{\log k\,})$.
**Turbo** gave
[this link](http://www.cs.ou.edu/~qcheng/paper/factorial.pdf)
to a 2004 paper by Qi Cheng that spells out this connection;
that's perhaps surprisingly late, since Lenstra's ECM paper dates back to 1987 $-$
I found some e-mails from 1996 where I noted that ECM suggests that
some multiple of $k!$ can be computed in a number of operations subexponential in $\log k$,
and I wouldn't be surprised if Lenstra himself noticed this some years earlier.
Note that likewise the counterexamples involving $2^{16}-2^4$ etc. that
I started with are in effect using
Pollard's
$p-1$ factorization method.

I tried to estimate how well this would work for $k = 10^7$
compared with the prime-factorization technique.
There are $664579$ primes $p < 10^7$, so any route to $k!$ via
prime factorization would have to take at least $2 \cdot 664579$ steps
(one to reach each $p$ and one to multiply by it).
For the ECM approach to some multiple of $k!$, I tried the following experiment.
For each of the first $96$ isogeny classes of rank-$1$ elliptic tables in
Cremona's table (these being the first two columns of Table 2 on page 235 of
his *Algorithms for Modular Elliptic Curves*, covering conductors $N \leq 220$),
choose a curve $E_i$ and a generator $P_i$
($i \leq 96$).  Then, for each prime $p \leq 10^7$, factor the order of
each $P_i \bmod p$ using the built-in **gp** command **ellorder**,
factor it as $\prod_j l_j^{e_j}$, and note the minimal value $m(p)$ of
$\max_j l_j^{e_j}$ over the $96$ choices of $(E_i,P_i)$;
thus for each $p$ there's some $i$ for which the order of $P_i \bmod p$
is a product of prime powers $\leq m(p)$.
This took a few hours.
The largest $m(p)$ observed is $379$, for $p = 6978421$.
But about 90% of these primes have $m(p) \leq 83$.
(There are $67608$ primes $p\leq 10^7$ with $m(p)>83$; 
also $47193$ with $m(p)>100$ and $22518$ with $m(p)>113$.)
There are $23$ primes $l \leq 83$; let $M = 2^6 3^4 5^2 7^2 \prod_{l=11}^{83} l$,
and compute for each $i$ a nonzero multiple $D_i$ of the denominator of $M P_i$,
which requires about $150$ group-law additions in $E_i$ because $M \approx 2^{122.6}$.
Then form $\prod_{i=1}^{96} D_i$, multiply by the product of the $67608$
missing primes, and square the whole thing $23$ times to get a multiple
of $10^7!$.  I don't know how many arithmetic operations it takes these days
to do an elliptic-curve addition or subtraction, but it must be under $40$,
and this already puts us under half our estimate for computing $10^7!$ itself
via prime factorization ($96 \cdot 150 \cdot 40 = 600000$).  There's probably a significant additional factor to be saved by
using more curves $E_i$, balancing the $m(p)$ cutoff, and choosing
$E_i$ that allow for faster group operations such as [Edwards curves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edwards_curve).

Comment: Is some factorization algorithm which "factors" k! of use, say Rho: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm

Comment: That's a good thought, but it seems one can compute $k!$ itself 
determinstically in $k^{1/2+\epsilon}$ operations, and
(as in effect noted by **Turbo**) if you use ECM 
(the elliptic curve method for (the elliptic curve 
method for finding moderately-sized prime factors of large numbers)
you get a heuristically subexponential route to some large multiple of $k!$.
I intend to write more about this, but not now because I must go to sleep!

Comment: Good night :) So we are trying to compute a multiple of primorial as fast as possible and then keep squaring.

Comment: 1,2,3,6,36,72,70,  so t(5040) is at most 8.  Have not found a shorter string yet.

Comment: You can also generate primes by generating the gaps first. For k less than 18 decimal digits this is less than O((log k)^2) .

Comment: There may also be a computation string which consists solely of all the primes and their powers, possibly in increasing order.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies Strassen has a technique which constructs $k!$ with ring operations in $O(k^{1/2}log k)$ steps. Again refer page 2 in http://www.cs.ou.edu/~qcheng/paper/factorial.pdf gives references 4,14. So we know at every k large enough $t(k!)\approx ck^{1/2+\epsilon}$ holds ($k$ need not be a square).

Comment: Once we have $t(k!) \ll k^{1/2+\epsilon}$ for $k=m^2$, 
we get the same estimate automatically for all $k$ by
writing $k = m^2 + q$ with $0 \leq q \leq 2m$ and
multiplying $m^2!$ by the missing $q = O(k^{1/2})$ factors
one at a time.  Still $k^{1/2} \log k$ (or even $k^{1/2} \log^2 k$, which is what your reference says) looks better by a log factor or two than what I cited.

Comment: So sorry. what is this comment "but proving $t(k!)\gg k^{1/2 }$seems to be beyond reach"? You mean removing $\epsilon$ factor?

Comment: No, I mean that we have no way to prove that
there's no more than an $\epsilon$ factor to remove.
Just because so far we've found nothing shorter than $k^{1/2}$
doesn't mean that there's no way to get to $k!$ in $k^{o(1)}$
operations, or even a number of operations polynomial in $\log k$.

Comment: It seems that Qi Cheng (Theoretical Computer Science 326 (2004), 419-429) proves an upper bound of the form $t(a n!) \ll \exp(c\sqrt{\log n \log\log n})$ (for some suitable $a$ depending on $n$) assuming a standard conjecture on the distribution of smooth number in short intervals, similarly to what you use when analyzing ECM. According to Cheng, the essential part of the proof is based on ECM.

Comment: PS. This is the paper already mentioned in Turbo's answer.

Comment: Well, I didn't read all the papers. A feature of n! is that is n-smooth. You can easily construct EC y^2=x^3+ax+b and point P=(X,Y) s.t. 2P=0 mod n! (compute with div. poly.) . Appears to me in this scenario the problem is to construct {a,b,X}. Is it known that nonzero multiple of $n!$ can't be computed fast via $x \mapsto poly(x) \mod n!$"?

Comment: How about the following analysis is started: for each value n computed with t(n)=c, find the largest value k so that k! divides n.  Compute kk =max k taken over all n with t(n)=c.  Perhaps info is hiding in n/kk for small c.  Gerhard "Try Brute Force, Applied Smartly" Paseman, 2015.02.02

Comment: FYI extended the question for bounds for $t(a n!)$ for nonzero $a$.

Comment: For fast operations on EC check http://hyperelliptic.org/EFD/

Comment: The usual game is to minimize multiplications, not counting $+$ and $-$ which are practically free in comparison.  Here we're assigning each of $+,-,\times$ the same cost, so the leaders in hyperelliptic.org/EFD may not be best for us.

Comment: From complexity point of view, is computing _multiple_ of factorial as powerful as computing factorial? IIRC sub-exponential SAT solver might cause troubles.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies could you post your email transcripts? Is your method different from Cheng's?

Comment: Basically the same method, yes, though I only hinted at it in the e-mail
(to Pascal Koiran, following up a discussion at a May 1996 DIMACS conference
apparently occasioned by a conversation with Michael Shub).  
I see that then too I began with the $2^N-1$ tactic.
The e-mail is too long for a comment here so I'm not sure how you'd want me
to post it here.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies In Qi Cheng's paper on calculating $ak!$ at some random $a\in\Bbb N$, what is the probability that given an integer $T$, $\mathsf{gcd}(a,T)=1$? In general, is number of trials of Lenstra's $\mathsf{ECM}$ needed to guarantee $\mathsf{gcd}(a,T)=1$ with probability $1-\mathsf{o}(1)$ also sub-exponential $\mathsf{exp}(\sqrt{\log k})$?

Answer (score 5):

$t(ak!)$ could have sub-exponential complexity (atleast in a randomized sense) at some $a\in\Bbb N$. Please refer interesting paper http://www.cs.ou.edu/~qcheng/paper/factorial.pdf.

My personal opinion is there is no polynomially many $\{+,-,\times\}$-operation algorithm to construct factorial in a deterministic sense.

However I do believe one of the two possibilities (possibly both) to be true:

1. The $exp(\sqrt{\log n})$ can be brought to $O((\log n)^c)$ in a randomized sense at a fixed $c>0$.
2. No deterministic algorithm can achieve $O((\log n)^c)$ $\{+,-,\times\}$-operations at any fixed $c>0$.

Comment: so it may very well be unthinkable could happen ultimately.

Comment: FYI extended the question for bounds for $t(a n!)$ for nonzero $a$.

Comment: From complexity point of view, is computing _multiple_ of factorial as powerful as computing factorial? IIRC sub-exponential SAT solver might cause troubles.

Comment: If we guarantee the multiple avoids primes of interest. then yes.

Answer (score 4):

The post above has a link to the term-complexity measure based on size of a term
computing a number.  The following different model is from my memory of the BCSS paper, so verification would be appreciated.

For this problem, I define a computation string be a finite sequence of integers $a_i$,
with $ 1  \leq i \leq n$, which obeys the following properties:

1. $a_1 = 1$
2. For every $i$ with $1 \lt i \leq n$, there is an allowed operation (say $++$) and indices $j$ and $k$ with $1 \leq j,k \lt i$ such that $a_i= a_j ++ a_k$.  Note that $j$ can equal $k$.

Then over all such computation strings of varying lengths which contain an integer $s$,
pick the shortest one, say of length $n$, and set $t(s)=n$.

Generally the allowed operations are total and are a fixed finite set, specified in advance.  For the set with addition, subtraction, and multiplication, one can form at
most $(n!)^23^n$ distinct computation strings of length $n+1$, and one can use
associativity and commutativity to cut down on the bound.  It is clear the largest number
formed is $2^{2^n}$ in a computation string of length $n+1$.  It is not clear that one
can arrange a computation of $s$ of length $t(s)$ and at the same time avoid repeats as well as having $a_{i+1}$ depend on $a_i$ for all $1 \lt i \lt n$.  Indeed one may need
to compute two or three numbers of complexity $t$ and put them in the string for later use.

I hope to update this with a small program that does efficient listing of small computation strings, so that one can get an idea of how $t(n!)$ grows with $n$.

EDIT 2015.01.29  Awk code added to generate small computation strings

```
BEGIN{ SEP= "," ; SEP2 = ";" ; MAX = 40
heap[1]= SEP2 1  #empty computation string followed by possible values for next value
for(newidx=idx=1; newidx < MAX; idx++) {
   # read next computation string and possible next values
   split(heap[idx],stuff,SEP2) ; csqlen=split(substr(stuff[1],1+length(SEP)),csq,SEP)
   vlen=split(stuff[2],vs,SEP)
   for(i=1; i<= vlen; i++) {val=vs[i]
      scsqval=sortme(val); print "Sorted" scsqval
      if ( !(scsqval in db) ) { db[scsqval]=1; outv=""
         addvalues(val,val)
         for(j=1; j <= csqlen; j++) { addvalues((v=csq[j]), val) }
         for(j=1; j <= vlen; j++) { newvals[vs[j]]=1 }      
         ### remove redundant values
         for(j=1; j <= csqlen; j++) { if ((v=csq[j]) in newvals) delete newvals[v] }
         if (val in newvals) delete newvals[val]
         for (v in newvals) { outv = outv SEP v; delete newvals[v] }
         newidx++; heap[newidx] = stuff[1] SEP val SEP2 substr(outv,1+length(SEP))
         print heap[newidx] } }
    for (v in csq) delete csq[v]; for (v in vs) delete vs[v]; for (v in stuff) delete stuff[v]}
}  


function addvalues(a,b) {  newvals[a*b]=newvals[a+b]=newvals[a-b]=newvals[b-a]=1 }

function sortme(vv){ tmps=""
  for(ii=1; ii<=csqlen;ii++) ccsq[ii]=csq[ii]
  ccsq[(newlen=csqlen+1)]=vv
  for(ii=1; ii<=newlen;ii++)  for(jj=ii+1; jj <= newlen; jj++) {
          if (ccsq[ii] > ccsq[jj]) { t=ccsq[jj] ; ccsq[jj]=ccsq[ii] ; ccsq[ii]=t } }
  for(ii=1; ii<=newlen;ii++) {tmps = tmps SEP ccsq[ii] ; delete ccsq[ii] }
  return tmps }
```

END EDIT 2015.01.29

ADDED 2015.01.30

I am running computations to get strings of length 8.  I invite verification of
the following tuples $(i,t[i])$: (1,1) (2,2) (6,4) (24,5) (120,7) (720,7) (5040,8) .

Of course one has $t[n!]$ is less than $2n$, and by using prime powers and certain
assumptions on the distribution of primes, one can likely prove that for every
$\epsilon$ there is $n_0$ so that for $n > n_0$ one has $t[n!] \lt (1 + \epsilon) n$.  If one did not have subtraction, it might be possible to prove a linear in $n$ lower bound
on $t[n!]$.

The number of computationally distinct terms (I identify permuted strings) follows
the pattern (1,1) (2,2), (3,3) (4,7) (5,25) (6,115) (7,714) (8,x) where x is at least
2403. If anyone verifies these numbers, I invite them to make an OEIS entry.

END ADDED 2015.01.30

Gerhard "Ask Me About Small Programming" Paseman, 2015.01.27

Comment: As a check in understanding the model for plus, times and minus, I have 1 1, 1 0, and 1 2 as length 2 computation strings.  Tossing out redundant and computationally equivalent strings, I get 1 0 -1, 1 0 2, 1 2 -1, 1 2 3, and 1 2 4 as (isomorphism class representatives of) strings of length 3.  Gerhard "But Still Having Super-Exponential Growth" Paseman, 2015.01.27

Comment: Rough upper bound will be the solution with 1s "compressed". Common terms reused and long sums (if any) computed faster. In the solution with 1s they use the inequality ||a+b|| <= ||a||+||b|| and ||a b|| <= ||a||+||b||. I am not sure these  hold for t(n).

Comment: Actually, stronger inequalities hold, as the computations for a and b will share at least 1 common term, usually more.  So norm(a op b) will be at most norm(a) + norm(b) - 1, since the 1 does not have to be repeated.  The lower bounds are what are important.  Gerhard "Ask Me About Integer Complexity" Paseman, 2015.01.29

Comment: Further, if you analyze the small sequences, you will find a lot of "converging" paths, and not so many "diverging" paths.  So the inequality above will be sharp almost none of the time.  Gerhard "Still Looking For Better Bounds" Paseman, 2015.01.29

Comment: Appears the inequalities are of use :). So you can't prove it with lower bound because of 2^{2^n}} and similar?

Comment: In your code which is n and which is t(n)?

Comment: for some value of idx, heap[idx] contains a computation string of length csqlen, followed by a list of values that are candidates for appending to the string.  The first time I see a value n (stored in vs), t(n) will be csqlen+1.  I am computing t(5040) now, and it is taking a while.  I will update shortly.  The values in vs[i] are rather scattered; I  find it challenging to say anything about a lower bound for any number smaller than $2^{2^n}$ and bigger than $-(2^{2^{n-1}})$.  Gerhard "Waiting Till This Run Ends" Paseman, 2015.01.30

Comment: As a clue on how woolly it gets, I have 1,2,3,4,12,10,120 as one string and 1,2,3,9,27,729,720 as another.  Gerhard "And There Are Likely Others" Paseman, 2015.01.30

Comment: Interestingly, 1,2,4,5,7,7,8 shows up in OEIS as a partial sum transform of another sequence involving Hamming distance of n from certain small multiples of factors of n.  Maybe worth following up?  Gerhard "Having Too Much Fun Now" Paseman, 2015.01.30

Comment: Thanks. Would you please give the tuples (n,t(n!),t(2^2^k)) where k is the smallest s.t. n!<2^2^k? (In your code "Sorted" appears too big to me for 2^2^3=(((1+1)^2)^2)^2, likely my mistake.). In addition if you computationally find $t(a k!) < t(k!)$ this will answer the second question.

Comment: Is some factorization algorithm which "factors" k! of use, say Rho: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm

Comment: I have checked that $t(n!)$ is as given by Gerhard Paseman for $n \le 7$ and also that $t(8!) > 8$. I used the Magma code given in my next comment to list all possible computations of up to 8 steps (in under 15 seconds on my laptop).

Comment: step := func<s | {t where t := {Include(s, f(a,b)) : a, b in s, f in ['+','-','*']} | #t gt #s}>; gens ;= [{{1}}]; for n := 2 to 8 do l := gens[#gens]; time Append(~gens, &join{step(s) : s in l}); end for;

Comment: (Sorry for the dense code; I haven't found a way to get line breaks in comments).

Comment: Correction to the code above: the first two statements should read step := func<s | {t : a, b in s, f in ['+','-','*'] | #t gt #s where t := Include(s, f(a,b))}>; gens := [{{1}}]; [it was too late to edit...]

Comment: According to this computation, the counts of the integers that are computable in $n$ steps are as follows: $1, 3, 6, 13, 38, 153, 867, 6930$. There are no factorials beyond $7!$ that show up for $n \le 8$. In particular, $t(8!) = 9$.

Comment: There are lots of length-7 computations of 120, but only five (up to permutation) for 720: (1,2,3,9,81,80,720), (1,2,3,9,27,729,720), (1,2,3,9,81,729,720), (1,2,4,6,24,30,720) and (1,2,4,16,20,36,720). There are twenty of length 8 for 5040 (two of which involve $-70$ and $-72$...).

Comment: $7! = (-70) (-72)$ is amusing, but as long as your target is positive you needn't bother with negative intermediate results because their absolute values work too.

Comment: FYI extended the question for bounds for $t(a n!)$ for nonzero $a$.

Comment: From complexity point of view, is computing _multiple_ of factorial as powerful as computing factorial? IIRC sub-exponential SAT solver might cause troubles.

Answer (score 4):

(Added 2015-02-01)

Perhaps the most relevant part of this answer is the reference to
[A217032](http://oeis.org/A217032),
which gives the following values for $t(n!)$, $1 \le n \le 19$:
$$1,2,4,5,7,7,8,9,9,10,10,11,12,12,13,13,13,14,14.$$

The problem whether $t(n!)$ can be bounded by a polynomial in $\log n$
(in the paper by Shub and Smale, see near the bottom of this answer)
*must* be open, since a positive answer would imply a polynomial time
factorization algorithm (assuming a straight-line program for $n!$
can also be *constructed* in time polynomial in $\log n$).

---

My comments to Gerhard Paseman's answer get a bit many and long, so it may be better to put all of this together in an answer.

I use the following Magma code to find all possible computations up to a given length.

> `step := func<s | {t : a, b in s, f in ['+','-','*']
>                       | #t gt #s where t := Include(s, f(a,b))}>;
>   gens := [{{1}}];
>   for n := 2 to 8 do
>     l := gens[#gens];
>     Append(~gens, &join{step(s) : s in l});
>   end for;`

The result of the computation is a set of integers; the next step adds an
element that is a sum, difference or product of two elements in the set.
I keep only sets that are larger than before, i.e., computations that
do not repeat numbers. The numbers of these sets for lengths 1 to 8 are

1, 2, 5, 20, 149, 1852, 34354, 873386.

The counts for the number of distinct integers that can be computed are

1, 3, 6, 13, 38, 153, 867, 6930.

The factorials $n!$ first show up at step 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 7, 8
(for $1 \le n \le 7$). No other factorial occurs up to length 8.

There are two computations of length 4 that compute 6:
(1, 2, 3, 6) and (1, 2, 4, 6).

There is only one of length 5 for 24: (1, 2, 4, 6, 24).

There are close to 50 computations of length 7 for 120, but only five for 720:

(1, 2, 3, 9, 27, 729, 720), (1, 2, 3, 9, 81, 729, 720),
(1, 2, 3, 9, 81, 80, 720), (1, 2, 4, 6, 24, 30, 720)
and (1, 2, 4, 16, 20, 36, 720).

(All of this up to permutation.) There are 20 computations of length 8 of 5040,
some of them containing 8 and 72, for example (1, 2, 4, 8, 9, 72, 70, 5040).
It follows that $t(8!) = t(9!) = 9$. In fact, there are 94 computations
of $8!$ and 18 of $9!$. I did run through all length-9 computations to
check that (and also that $10!$ does not show up, so $t(10!) \ge 10$),
generating them from the length-8 sets in gens[8],
which took a few minutes, but I couldn't save all length-9 computation
sets, because there are too many.

Added later: $t(10!) = 10$, one possibility being
$(1,2,3,5,7,12,144,720,720^2,10!)$.

Further results:

- For all $n \ge 10$, $t(n!) \ge 10$.
- $t(11!) = 10$, for example $(1,2,3,9,81,80,77,720,720^2,11!)$

---

Thomas Sauvaget in the comment below points out that the sequence 1, 3, 6, 13, 38, ... mentioned above is [A216999](http://oeis.org/A216999)
in the OEIS (see also [A173419](http://oeis.org/A173419)).
The OEIS links to [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=B2AF46B7D3040B916A1989BA53214E63?doi=10.1.1.100.5035&rep=rep1&type=pdf) by Shub and Smale [this is probably what the
book [BCS+97] that is mentioned in the Question refers to],
where the following problem is formulated on page 3:

> **Problem.** Is there a constant $c$ such that
>   $$\tau(k!) \le (\log k)^c$$
>   for all $k$?

Their $\tau(n)$ is our $t(n)$. This is then related to the "intractability"
of the Hilbert Nullstellensatz over $\mathbb C$.

From looking at the references to this paper in MathSciNet, my impression
is that this problem is still open, but it is hard to know for sure.

The sequence $(t(n!)-1)$ is [A217032](http://oeis.org/A217032).
This gives the following values for $t(n!)$, $1 \le n \le 19$:
$$1,2,4,5,7,7,8,9,9,10,10,11,12,12,13,13,13,14,14.$$
(Which is consistent with the data I have computed, but goes quite a bit
further.)

Comment: It seems that the OEIS has 1, 3, 6, 13, 38, 153, 867, 6930 as A216999 with some more references.

Comment: Since you ask about line breaks in comments, here is latex approach. I believe this can be done in a single texttt$$\texttt{line1}$$
$$\texttt{line2}$$

Comment: FYI extended the question for bounds for $t(a n!)$ for nonzero $a$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is partial result about multiple of factorial
based on heuristic code.

By the [paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=B2AF46B7D3040B916A1989BA53214E63?doi=10.1.1.100.5035&rep=rep1&type=pdf) Michael Stoll cites,

$t(m) \le 2 \log{m}$.

By repeated squaring $t(a^{2^k}) \le t(a)+k$.

Let $M=\log{n}$ and $S=\{a \cdot b^{2^k}+c : 1\le a \le 2M, 1\le b\le 2M, -
2M \le c \le 2M, 0\le k \le M\}$.

First we try to compute primorial $n$ and then square few times.

Members of $S$ can be computed in polynomial in $\log{n}$ time.

So it depends if few members of $S$ contain all primes $\le n$.

Let $\{P\}$ be the set of primes $\le n$.

Greedy Algorithm 1. For $ a,b \in S$ and $c= a \{+,-,\times\} b$
find the $c$ which is divisible by largest number of members of $P$.
Keep $c$ and remove the primes from $P$. Repeat. Terminate when $P$
is empty. I can't prove this always terminate ;).

Certainly $S$ can be extended by the other answers.

Here is algorithm (1) for multiples of $45\#$ and $55\#$:

```
sage: greedyfactorial(45,planc=False,allb=1)
#S= 1637
1 9 [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 31, 41] -340282366920938463463374607431768211200 = (1*2^8+0)-(1*2^128+0)
early 2 5 [19, 23, 29, 37, 43] 10301051460877537454126135158480 = (1*5^16+6)+(3*3^64+6)
sage: greedyfactorial(55,planc=False,allb=1)
#S= 5821
1 11 [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 31, 37, 41] -39402006196394479212279040100143613805079739270465446667948293404245721771497210611414266254884915640806627973529600 = (1*2^24+0)-(1*2^384+0)
2 4 [23, 29, 47, 53] 19295810734578656668031216686940366563098640636282442092649989 = (6*2^8+1)*(2*2^192+5)
early 3 1 [43] 258 = 1+(1*2^8+1)
```

Sage code written in a hurry:

```
def greedyfactorial(n,deg=2,allb=True,planc=False):
    pri=list(primes(2,n+1)) #primorial
    k=floor(log(n))^deg
    lk=2*floor(log(n))
    pri1=[ 0 .. lk ]        
    pows=[]
    for p in pri1:
        if p==0:  continue
        for e in [ 2 .. lk]:
            pows += [p**(2**e)]
    pri1=[(i,str(i)) for i in pri1[:]]
    S=pri1[:]
    ca={}
    for p,_ in S:  ca[p]=1

    for p,_ in pri1:
      for q,_ in pri1:
        for b in pows:
            T=p*b+q
            if T in ca:  continue
            ca[T]=1
            S += [(p*b+q,'('+str(p)+'*'+str(factor(b))+ '+'+str(q)+')')]
            T=p*b-q
            if T in ca:  continue
            ca[T]=1
            S += [(p*b+q,'('+str(p)+'*'+str(factor(b))+ '-'+str(q)+')')]
    S=[(i,j) for i,j in S if i!=0]
    B=[(1,'1')]
    if allb:  B=S

    ops2=[ (lambda x,y:  x*y,'*'),(lambda x,y:  x + y,'+'), (lambda x,y:   x - y,'-')]
    print '#S=',len(S)
    def countp(A,S):
        r=[]
        for p in S:
            if A%p==0:  r += [p]
        return r    

    S=uniq(S)

    for ste in [ 1 .. k]:
        ma,br,BA=0,[],0
        for a,an in S:
            #for b,bn in S:
            for b,bn in B:
                for f,o in ops2:
                    A=f(a,b)
                    if A==0:  continue
                    r=countp(A,pri)
                    if len(r)>ma:
                        br=r
                        bs=an+o+bn
                        ma=len(r)
                        BA=A
                        if ma==len(pri):
                            print 'early',ste,ma,br,BA,'=',bs
                            return
                    if planc and ma>=len(pri)//2:  break    
                if planc and ma>=len(pri)//2:  break    

        print ste,ma,br,BA,'=',bs
        pri=[p for p in pri if not p in br]
        if pri==[]:
            print ' Done'
            return
```