# Consequences failure of $\tau$ conjecture

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-complexity

A question [Bounds for constructing $n!$ with additions, subtractions, and multiplications starting from $1$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/194751/bounds-for-constructing-n-with-additions-subtractions-and-multiplications-s) was asked on constructing $ak!$ with ring operations.

$\tau$ conjecture states if $\exists$ no infinite sequence of integers $n_k$ such that $k!n_k$ could be constructed in polylogarithmic number of ring operations, then $P_C\neq NP_C$ in BSS model.

Is there any consequence if $\tau$ conjecture fails?